# ASP.NET 3.0 Authorize failed route

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, routes, authorize

I am wondering what is the best way to gracefully handle when a user is not authorized on a webpage. In 3.0 Microsoft introduced the idea of Identity area for users, but it appears the [Authorize()] has not been migrated over. Here is what I mean:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public class IndexMode : PageModel
{
```

If the user navigates to this page it defaults to "/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FHome%2Findex"
But in 3.0 it really should be:"/Identity/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FHome%2Findex"

Now this make since because the use isn't authorized so they probably need to be logged in (however it may be possible the user just isn't authorized.

What is the best way to handle these two base cases?